# Bind value doesn't work, always takes empty

Tags: knockout.js

I have a table with two fields: day and hour, but only day field takes value, maybe it's a knockout bug or something weird I can't understand is happing.

This is the view (jade rather html):

```
                p
                    label(for='dates') Datas
                        span.required *
                        &nbsp
                        span(data-bind='visible: dates().length > 1')
                    ul#list-dates(data-bind='foreach: dates()')
                        li
                            div.form-inline
                                input.input-small(type='text', name='dateDay', data-bind='value: day, hasfocus: true')
                                span -
                                input.input-mini(type='text', name='dateHour', date-bind='value: hour')
                                a.btn(href='#', data-bind='click: $root.addDate')
                                    i.icon-plus
```

This is the javascript:

```
var DateModel = function(day, hour) {
    var self = this;
    self.day = ko.observable(day);
    self.hour = ko.observable(hour);
};

function DateViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.dates = ko.observableArray([
        new DateModel("", "")
    ]);

    self.addDate = function() {
        var pos = self.dates().length;
        pos = pos-1;

        console.log("Day: " + self.dates()[pos].day());
        console.log("Hour: " + self.dates()[pos].hour());

        if (self.dates()[pos].day() != '' && self.dates()[pos].hour() != '')
            self.dates.push(new DateModel("", ""));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new DateViewModel());
```

When addDate is pressed it suppose to check day and hour entries added before to create new fields. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "hour" binding is not working because **you have miss-typed the** `data-bind` attribute.

You have:

```
input.input-mini(type='text', name='dateHour', date-bind='value: hour')
```

Which should be

```
input.input-mini(type='text', name='dateHour', data-bind='value: hour')
```

Comment: Thanks nemesv, was my fault. Worked for me. The first field seems to be weird, a weird behaviour, it requires to tabs to blur I think it's because the "hasfocus" property. I'll check out some solution for it. Ty again!